# How to convert values into a time format but not date format

Tags: r, datetime

```
mydata
10:17:37
09:48:11
10:20:25
10:52:12
10:52:08
10:47:42
09:57:13
```

1. How do i convert these values into time format (only time)?
2. Could you also provide me the code for date and time ?

Answer (score 2):

We can use the `times` from `chron`

```
library(chron)
library(dplyr)
mydata %>%
     mutate(v1 = times(v1))
```

Or with `hms` from `lubridate`

```
library(lubridate)
mydata %>%
     mutate(v1 = hms(v1))
```

If we need the current date and 'time'

```
mydata %>% 
      mutate(v1 = as.POSIXct(v1, format = "%H:%M:%S"))
```

#### data

```
mydata <- structure(list(v1 = c("10:17:37", "09:48:11", "10:20:25", "10:52:12", 
"10:52:08", "10:47:42", "09:57:13")), .Names = "v1", class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))
```